# Reporting platform for Asp.net - with excel/pdf/word export

Tags: asp.net, reporting-services, components

I am looking for a reporting platform for our asp.net application, which will allow the report to be exported in excel (for tabular data), or PDF/Word (for document reports like Invoice prints).

Are there any standard options available?

I tried Rdlc, but it does not seem to help in the second case (at least I dint see a way, if you can please enlighten me :) ).

Currently we are using Interop for excel export (I know its not recommended for asp.net, we are planning to switch soon), use rtf templates for word reports (which also makes them somewhat customizable) and we dont have pdf export (planning to build it). But it seems like a waste of effort if standard controls are already available!

Cheaper the better! Free rocks!!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

What's the issue with Rdlc? You can create any kind of format into it. For invoice prints etc you can use [list](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms159121.aspx) data region. Its used for free flow kind of stuff. Its like ASP.NET repeater. In your case, you will have only one row of data.

Edit: even Crystal reports has equivalent functionality. As said, you will have only one row of data for invoices etc.

In both Crystal & RDLC, you can even supply multiple rows of data to your free flow report and generate multiple invoices in one go. Can be very helpful feature for users.

Comment: That makes sense - 

Crystal reports have complicated licensing terms - a couple of years back I checked it was runtime license, recently I saw some developer license without runtime, etc. 

But Reportviewer with list should work fine! Thanks!!